# Dynamically create text in dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

How can I dynamically set the text of the dialog box that I'm opening? I've tried a few different things but they all respond with an empty dialog box.

Here is my current try:

```
$('#dialog').text('Click on the link to download the file:
'.data);
$('#dialog').dialog("open");
```

Comment: ha, too much php before I wrote that; thanks for the sarcasm though, it was helpful!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For best practice, try putting a div inside your dialog div and appending text to that instead.

```
<div id="myDialog"><div id="myDialogText"></div></div>
```

and then setting the text of the internal Div.  This make for better separation, so you have

- a div for dialog manipulation
- and a div for text display

You can then set the text with

```
jQuery("#myDialogText").text("your text here");
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is an alternative way of creating dialogs on the fly and setting their messages dynamically:

```
$('<div></div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Confirmation",
    open: function() {
      var markup = 'Hello World';
      $(this).html(markup);
    },
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }   });  //end confirm dialog
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/DYbwb/

Comment: The div should be destroyed on close, shouldn't it? Also I don't like to set text on open event. You could create a Element, calling dialog and destroy it on close: http://jsfiddle.net/06nLLtbb/1/

Comment: it's about a year after you posted this and i am very happy you did.

Comment: A relevant/related link about destroying the "on-the-fly" dialog element: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2864740/2943403

Answer (score 4):

Use the plus symbol to concatenate strings:

```
$('#dialog').text('Click on the link to download the file:
' + data);
$('#dialog').dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing dynamic text in a jQueryui dialog box.  The text is from an ajax response.  The message is shown below (larger than it appears!).[image]

```
$(".info").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'my_code.php',
           data: {query:"info", rowid: $id},
           success: function(data) {
                try {
                   obj = JSON.parse(data);
                   var str = '';
                   for (var i in obj) {
                       str += i + ":" + obj[i] + "<br />";
                       if (i == "id") str += "<hr />";
                   }
                   $("#dialog-1").html(str).dialog();
                   $("#dialog-1").dialog('open');
                } catch (e) {}
           }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dialog("open");` isn't a valid jquery UI method. (And what Mike said about concatenating with `+` instead of `.`

[Check the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).