# How to completely remove a dialog on close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When an ajax operation fails, I create a new div with the errors and then show it as a dialog. When the dialog is closed I would like to completely destroy and remove the div again. How can I do this? My code looks something like this at the moment:

```
$('<div>We failed</div>')
    .dialog(
    {
        title: 'Error',
        close: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).destroy().remove();
        }
    });
```

When I run this the dialog box shows up correctly, but when I close it the dialog is still visible in the html (using FireBug). What am I missing here? Something I have forgotten?

**Update:** Just noticed my code gives me an error in the firebug console.

> $(this).destroy is not a function

Anyone able to help me out?

**Update:** If I do just `$(this).remove()` instead, the item is removed from the html. But is it completely removed from the DOM? Or do I somehow need to call that destroy function first as well?

Answer (score 273, accepted):

```
$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
```

This will destroy the dialog and then remove the div that was "hosting" the dialog completely from the DOM

Comment: Note that `.destroy` removes the outer markup added by UI framework (titlebar, closebutton, resizebar etc). Perhaps this is what you meant by _host_.

Comment: becareful using this with FF and with Firebug opened. It will crash. 
https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6290
I spent hours... to figure what wrong with my code.

Comment: If you are using a div from the DOM, so not dynamically created, use `.empty()`. Then you can reuse it, if you fill the contents again offcourse.

Comment: I have used $(this).dialog('destroy') because I dont want to remove the entire div (I need it again for reloading) . This cleasr the dom of chrome but does not work for firefox.Here is my code  close: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).dialog('destroy');      }

Comment: @HendryH., that no longer seems to be a problem with Firefox 23.0 and Firebug 1.11.4.

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Is `destroy` necessary? Won't removing the element also destroy the dialog?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124389/jquery-ui-how-to-remove-dynamic-element-after-dialog-closes

Comment: While this does work, it is horribly inefficient. the destroy method will attempt to [preserve the content of the dialog.](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) If you have a complicated dialog with lots of bindings on elements that were inside it, it can actually take *a few seconds* to destroy and remove the dialog. The solution is to run: `$(this).empty();` *immediately before* destroying the dialog and then removing the div. This reduces the time you would potentially have to wait to *zero*.

Answer (score 11):

Why do you want to remove it?

If it is to prevent multiple instances being created, then just use the following approach...

```
$('#myDialog') 
    .dialog( 
    { 
        title: 'Error', 
        close: function(event, ui) 
        { 
            $(this).dialog('close');
        } 
    });
```

And when the error occurs, you would do...

```
$('#myDialog').html("Ooops.");
$('#myDialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: I just thought it would be easier, since it will contain different content depending on what I get back from an ajax call. And also the div isn't static like I showed in my example but rendered by the http://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl plugin. If you have a good way of swapping out the contents of the dialog I would be interested in seeing that though :)

Comment: Well, in my example, I went with the extremely simple option of just dumping a string withing the dialog div: $('#myDialog').html("Ooops.");
You could modify this to change the content of any sub-controls in the dialog div as well.

Comment: This is not a great approach as all dialogOptions will remain on the #myDialog unless you override them specifically.

The second dialog should not (always) have the same buttons, height, etc.. as the first one.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(dialogElement).empty();

$(dialogElement).remove();
```

this fixes it for real

Answer (score 5):

This is worked for me

```
$('<div>We failed</div>')
    .dialog(
    {
        title: 'Error',
        close: function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Cheers!

**PS:** I had a somewhat similar problem and the above approach solved it.

Comment: You're calling the close method from within the close callback! jQuery UI is smart enough to prevent the infinite loop that is suggested by this, but it's still redundant, and I definitely wouldn't consider it elegant.

Comment: At the time of writing the answer, without the `$(this).dialog("close");`, the dialog simply wouldn`t go away. jQuery at times is very weird.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution that works like a charm for me:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog(
    open: function(){
        $('div.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
        $("div.ui-dialog").not(':first').remove();
}
});
```

Comment: kind of weird its working at all. you open the dialog and immediately remove it...

Answer (score 1):

You can do use

```
$(dialogElement).empty();    
$(dialogElement).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function in all my js projects

You call it:
    hideAndResetModals("#IdModalDialog")

You define if:

```
function hideAndResetModals(modalID)
{
    $(modalID).modal('hide');
    clearValidation(modalID); //You implement it if you need it. If not, you can remote this line
    $(modalID).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () 
    {
        $(modalID).find('form').trigger('reset');  
    });
}
```