# JQuery dialog, strange behavior

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery's dialog with a textbox and input submit inside. When I submit the data, I can alert the textbox data from inside the JQuery function. This works great until I close the window using the [X] in the upper right corner. Once I've clicked out, reopen the dialog and attempt to post more data from that window, all I am able to alert is an empty string. No matter how many times I reopen the dialog and attempt to see my data, I will always get an empty string.

If I refresh the page and start over, I can successfully submit as many times as I want, as long as I don't close the dialog. Once it's closed, I need to refresh the browser again to get it working again.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: got any code we can look at? maybe a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: [jquery: How to completely remove a dialog on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864740/jquery-how-to-completely-remove-a-dialog-on-close)

If you destroy and remove the object, it will work as expected.